# Hidden default constructor

Tags: c++

Why does the code below compile?

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test(int i) {}
    private:
        Test();
};

int main()
{
    // OK - uses Test(int i)
    Test test(5);

    // Error - Test() is private
    // Test test2;

   // Why does this compile? Test() is private!
   Test test3();
}
```

I would think that the last instanciation would fail to compile since the no-param constructor is private?

Comment: `Test test3();` is treated as a function declaration, not construction of object.

Comment: @RakibulHasan function declaration*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test test3();` is a function declaration. It declares a function named `test3` of type `int()`. It's OK to declare things in C++, even if they're never defined (since you're not trying to actually call it).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sence.